# What is the difference between Vertex and Lattice?

Tags: geometry, graph-theory

From wikipedia:

### [Vertex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_(geometry))

In geometry, a vertex (in plural form: vertices or vertexes), often denoted by letters such as $P, Q, R, S, T$ is ***a point where two or more curves, lines, or edges meet.*** As a consequence of this definition, the point where two lines meet to form an angle and the corners of polygons and polyhedra are vertices.

[image]

### [Lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_graph)

A lattice graph, mesh graph, or grid graph, is a graph whose drawing, embedded in some Euclidean space $R^n$, forms a regular tiling.

[image]

### My question:

Wikipedia says vertex **is a point where two or more curves, lines, or edges meet.**

From the second picture, Isn't a lattice just a vertex? Is there a difference?

(All the pictures are taken from Wikipedia)

Comment: A lattice is a type of [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)), which is composed of both edges and vertices.  A vertex is what the point where edges meet is called, not the entire figure.

Comment: A lattice is $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}$ and in particular each point in the lattice have integer coordinates.

For other hand a vertex is any point that not necessary have integer entries.